# Quickfixj 2.3 - OutOfOrder exception while parsing the raw FIX mssage

Tags: quickfixj

we are using quickfixJ 2.3.
To parse and validate used DD, messageFactory .

MessageUtil.parse(msgFactory, dd, rawfixmsg,false).

This gives me OutOFOrderExceprion.

However  if I understand correctly, major tags are 8 followed by 9 in start of message ,and the end tag is 10.
Remaining tags could be anywhere ..after 9 tag and before 10 tag in message.

How could to achieve this ?

Comment: Remaining tags could be anywhere EXCEPT in repeating groups.

Comment: I was able to parse , I used DD for multileg and list order , and removed dd for others like NSo

Comment: Is there any other way ,to.provide support for Multileg order in 4.2 ? As we use dd for validation, it's getting failed at time of parsing